# Opposite of "arrogant"/"having attitude"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

1. Are *self-abased* and *humble* both opposite to *arrogant* or *having attitude*? What are their differences?
2. What are words for the opposite to *arrogant*, respectively in a positive, negative, and neutral way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both self-abased and humble can be considered as antonyms for arrogant. The difference between them in this context being

> Humble - Not showing arrogance in
>   spite of knowing that one is good.
>
> Self-abased - Not showing arrogance
>   because he feels he is not good.
>   (Inferiority complex, may be)

Some other antonyms for arrogant are

> Modest - Positive
>
> Shy - Neutral
>
> Meek, Servile, timid - Negative

Of course, whether something is positive, negative  or neutral will depend on the context it is spoken, people who are engaged in the conversation, how it is said etc. But I feel this can be considered as a broad classification.

Comment: I think it's true that "self-abased" suggests a lower self-cofnidence than "humble." But "not showing arrogance in spite of knowing that one is good" sounds more like false humility than true humility to me.

Comment: I would say that *shy* is often (but not always) negative, although if you think of someone as shy then you're likely to have pity for them, rather than contempt. At the very least I think it's common for shy people to wish they were less so. Contrast with antonyms for shy: *bold* or *assertive*, which are often (but not always) positive (unlike arrogant, which is negative).

Comment: @John Bartholomew, just for the sake of discourse, do you think 'shy' could be put opposite 'promiscuous', making it positive?

Comment: @John and @Karl, Shyness is considered a positive trait in girls in some cultures.

Comment: @Karl: Actually, I wouldn't put *shy* opposite *promiscuous*; to me, promiscuity is most importantly about choice or acceptance (not having any misgivings about having many shallow sexual relationships). Someone who is shy might be practically prevented from being promiscuous because they find it difficult to form relationships (sexual or otherwise) so quickly, but that doesn't mean they wouldn't *want* to.

Comment: @rest_day: You make a good point that it varies by culture. I may also be focusing too heavily on one usage of *shy*, certainly it can be used in a wider variety of ways than I've alluded to in my comments here.

Comment: Fair point, @John. I would agree with you, really; I was just trying to present a situation that fit the bill since I do think shy can be seen as a positive sometimes. @Rest_Day, yes. Perhaps it is based on culture more than anything else.

Comment: @senderle: false humility or more likely __false modesty__ is when you say something self abasing or modest, intending for people to take it is as though you really are quite good, when in fact you're not.

Comment: @Mitch, no, I don't think that's right. There's a definition [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/false-modesty?q=false+modesty) that's quite clear and correct.